# Boto3: Get autoscaling group name based on multiple tags

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I have a requirement to get the name of the autoscaling group based on its tags.

I have tried following code:

```
kwargsAsgTags = {
    'Filters': [
        {
            'Name': 'key',
            'Values': ['ApplicationName']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'value',
            'Values': ['my-app-name']
        }
    ]
}
```

by using above filter I can get the autoscaling group name but since I have same 'ApplicationName' tag used in multiple environments like dev/qa/uat, the output prints all autoscaling groups belong to all environments. How do I filter the EnvironmentName as well?

For that I've tried following but this time it prints all auto-scaling groups belonging to 'dev' environment as well.

```
kwargsAsgTags = {
    'Filters': [
        {
            'Name': 'key',
            'Values': ['ApplicationName', 'EnvName']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'value',
            'Values': ['my-app-name', 'dev']
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to understand your requirement. Could you please edit your question and provide a few examples of Auto Scaling groups with various tags, indicating which combination you are seeking to match?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - My requirement is to get autoscaling group name based on two tags - 1. ApplicationName 2. EnvName. How do I achieve this in boto3? e.g I need the name of the autoscalling group which has been tagged as -ApplicationName=SomeApp, EnvName=dev

Comment: Which command are you using to retrieve the Auto Scaling group name by tag? The `describe_auto_scaling_groups()` call does not accept a filter.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I'm using describe_tags() and it accepts filter

Comment: I don't think you can do it via a Filter on `describe_tags()`. The easiest method would probably be to use `describe_auto_scaling_group()` to retrieve all groups, then filter the response within your own code.